# Convert names of months to numbers

Tags: r

I have this variable month and I want to assign   corresponding numbers by creating a new variable like:

```
Month    New variable
January             1
February            2
April               4
March               3
```

I wanted to use ifelse but i got 4 conditions

here my initial code:

```
df$newvar=ifelse(df$month=="March"& df$month=="April",3,4)
```

Comment: It does'nt work.It was an example.My month variable look like this:Mar Mar Mar Apr Apr Jan Jan ...

Comment: `df$month=="March"& df$month=="April"` isn't going to evaluate to true anywhere, since you're checking that the month is both March & April

Comment: usually I use ifelse to assign values with 2 conditions like 0 or 1,but this time i want use for 4 conditions 1,2,3,4

Comment: If they are abbreviations, could you use `match(df$month, month.abb)`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`dplyr::case_when` solution

```
df <- data.frame(
  Month = c("January", "February", "April", "March")
)
df %>%
  mutate(New_var = case_when(
    Month == "January" ~ 1,
    Month == "February" ~ 2,
    Month == "April" ~ 4,
    Month == "March" ~ 3,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))

     Month New_var
1  January       1
2 February       2
3    April       4
4    March       3
```

Comment: This seems really inefficient, if not from a performance standpoint then just from the amount of typing and potential for typos. If you're going to match values from a single column/vector, why not just use something like `match`? Especially considering that R comes with a built-in table of month names and numbers to avoid doing something like this

Comment: @camille I was not sure if it's typo or not.

Comment: Not sure if what's a typo?

Comment: @camille I'm sorry. I though it was typo, February. I'm not good at english....

Comment: Ah, okay. No, unfortunately February is one of many words in English whose spelling makes no sense; the OP has it spelled correctly

Answer (score 0):

Make a second dataframe with the month names and their numbers, then merge.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Month = c("January", "February", "March", "April"))
df2 <- data.frame(Month = month.name, New = 1:12)

merge(df1, df2, sort = FALSE)
```

Result:

```
     Month New
1  January   1
2 February   2
3    March   3
4    April   4
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a mapping of month to number, so it is not necessary to use if-else,

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame( Month = c("January", "February", "April","March"))
months_number <- list(January=1,February=2,April=4,March=3)


df <- df %>% mutate(new_var=recode(Month,!!!months_number)) 
df
```